# FSM not working as expected (sequence detector 0110)

Tags: verilog, test-bench

I don't know what is wrong in the below code. It gives me output 1 only after adjusting my simulation delays properly. It gives me one after some different sequence. I cross-checked my logic several times. Please help me find my bugs.

[image: output]

**code**

```
module seq_0110(sequence_in,clock,reset,detector_out
    );
input clock; 
input reset; 
input sequence_in; 
output reg detector_out; 
reg [1:0] current_state, next_state; // current state and next state


always @(posedge clock, posedge reset)
begin
 if(reset==1) 
 current_state <=2'b00;// when reset=1, reset the state of the FSM to "Zero" State
 else
 current_state <= next_state; // otherwise, next state
end 

always @(current_state,sequence_in)
begin
 case(current_state) 
 2'b00:begin
  if(sequence_in==1)
   next_state <= 2'b00;
  else
   next_state <= 2'b01;
 end
 2'b01:begin
  if(sequence_in==1)
   next_state <= 2'b10;
  else
   next_state <= 2'b01;
 end
 2'b10:begin
  if(sequence_in==1)
   next_state <= 2'b11;
  else
   next_state <= 2'b01;
 end 
 2'b11:begin
  if(sequence_in==1)
   next_state <= 2'b00;
  else
   next_state <= 2'b01;
 end
 
 default:next_state <= 2'b00;
 endcase
end
// combinational logic to determine the output
// of the Moore FSM, output only depends on current state
always @(current_state)
begin 
 case(current_state) 
 2'b00:   detector_out <= 1'b0;
 2'b01:   detector_out <=1'b0;
 2'b10:  detector_out <= 1'b0;
 2'b11:  detector_out <=(sequence_in==1)?1'b0:1'b1;
 
 default:  detector_out <= 1'b0;
 endcase
end 
endmodule
```

Comment: you have issues with blocking/non-blocking assignments. Only the first always block, which is the flop, needs non-blocking. The rest should be blocking. You might have race conditions in current simulation because of it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your testbench and how you are displaying the signals in your log file.

In the testbench code you posted in [your other Question earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62021669/fsm-output-never-gets-set), you used `$monitor` to print the input and output signal.  The problem with that is `$monitor` only shows these signals if there is a change in either signal.  In your case, it would be much more meaningful to show these signals once per clock cycle.  This can be done using an `always` block and a `$display`, as follows:

```
always @(negedge clock) $display($time, " in=%b out=%b", sequence_in, detector_out);

initial begin
  $dumpfile("seq_0110.vcd");
  $dumpvars(0,seq_0110_t);
  sequence_in = 0;
  reset = 1;
  #30;
  reset = 0;

  repeat (5) @(posedge clock); sequence_in = 0;
             @(posedge clock); sequence_in = 1;
             @(posedge clock); sequence_in = 1;
             @(posedge clock); sequence_in = 0;

  repeat (5) @(posedge clock); sequence_in = 0;
             @(posedge clock); sequence_in = 1;
             @(posedge clock); sequence_in = 1;
             @(posedge clock); sequence_in = 0;

  repeat (5) @(posedge clock); sequence_in = 0;

  #10 $finish;
end
```

Now, the output clearly shows that your FSM detects the `0110` bit pattern on your input:

```
          10 in=0 out=0
          20 in=0 out=0
          30 in=0 out=0
          40 in=0 out=0
          50 in=0 out=0
          60 in=0 out=0
          70 in=0 out=0
          80 in=0 out=0
          90 in=1 out=0
         100 in=1 out=0
         110 in=0 out=1
         120 in=0 out=0
         130 in=0 out=0
         140 in=0 out=0
         150 in=0 out=0
         160 in=0 out=0
         170 in=1 out=0
         180 in=1 out=0
         190 in=0 out=1
         200 in=0 out=0
         210 in=0 out=0
         220 in=0 out=0
         230 in=0 out=0
         240 in=0 out=0
```